# Session Expiry VB.NET 1 Day

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am building an internal intranet system, that will call up sales orders and I need it to remember the last sales order number they were looking at, even though I could put this in a database and call up the info I was wondering if I could use a session cookie for a longer time than 20 minutes I want to set the expiry to expiry time to a day or a week or so;

```
Session("SalesOrder") = 105793 'STORE THIS FOR A DAY OR WEEK
```

I hope you can help.

Comment: Session objects are not meant for storing data for longer periods of time. When the AppPool is reset or recycled you will lose that data. Use Cookies or a database.

Comment: please can you explain using vb.net.

Comment: @Kiel explain what, precisely? BTW you can google any and all of the concepts VDWWD mentioned if you don't understand them.

Comment: I want to store a number in a cookie or session and not have it expire after 20 minutes of use. ATM they open a sales order be looking at it change page and come back and because the 20 minutes has expired they have to re-enter the sales order they are looking at again, this problem would go away if I could have it remember for more than 20 minutes. I probably could get away with setting it to an hour, because in that time they would have probably looked at another number and the timeout would have been reset.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx. MS documentation for reading and writing cookies.

Comment: Session expiration is per Session, not per Session Key. If you want different expirations per key you need different mechanisms (i.e. Caching). Btw, if you dont use a out of proc session don't store in sessions for such a long time (as VDWWD mentioned). This will return as a boomerang and usually causes more trouble than it does help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have just stored in the database now, it will keep what they are looking at forever.